# Change border color of a single cell inside a Table

Tags: vba, excel

I have a named table as range (list object) and I need to change the edge top border color of one cell but the code doesn´t works, i need some help. Here is part of the code:

```
With ws
    .Unprotect Password:="pAtRiCiA"

    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        If Left(ctrl.Name, 5) = "texto" Then
            If ultimafila - 1 <> 8 Then
                If ctrl.Name = "textoCausas" Then
                    If Not IsError(Application.Match(Me.textoCausas.Value, ws.ListObjects(ActiveSheet.Name).ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange, 0)) Then
                        .Cells(ultimafila, ctrl.TabIndex) = ""
                        .ListObjects(ActiveSheet.Name).ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange(ultimafila, 1).Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
                        .ListObjects(ActiveSheet.Name).ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange(ultimafila, 1).Borders(xlEdgeTop).ColorIndex = 3
                        .ListObjects(ActiveSheet.Name).ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange(ultimafila, 1).Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlThick
                    Else
                        .Cells(ultimafila, ctrl.TabIndex) = ctrl.Value
                    End If
                Else
                    .Cells(ultimafila, ctrl.TabIndex) = ctrl.Value
                End If
            Else
                .Cells(ultimafila, ctrl.TabIndex) = ctrl.Value
            End If
        End If
    Next ctrl
    .Cells(ultimafila, 2) = txtControles.Value

    .Rows(ultimafila).AutoFit
    .Rows(ultimafila).RowHeight = .Cells(ultimafila, 1).Height + 12
    .Protect Password:="pAtRiCiA", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
End With
```

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a very useful description of your problem. What happens when you run your code?

Comment: .Border properties aren't applied. The edge top border color of the cell is not changed after the macro is played.

Comment: Your border formatting lines work for me.  Are you sure they're getting executed?  If you place a break on one of those lines does the code stop there?

Comment: Yes the macro is executed. Code lines before and after `.Border` properties are executed. If I place a break the code stop there.

Answer (score 1):

With this test code:

```
Sub Test()

    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange(6, 1).Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 3
        .Weight = xlThick
    End With

End Sub
```

I get this result:

[image]

So, your formatting code works fine for me.
Do you maybe have some Conditional Formatting or some other formatting applied to that sheet?

Comment: Yes, now I see it works! The problem is that my table starts at row # 8, so the correct reference for the `DataBodyRange ` is `ultima fila - 8`. Thank you!